# Как создается пользователь в шаблоне advanced фрэймворка YII2?

Tags: yii2

Вопрос в принципе весь в теме описан, интересует, как создать пользователя (с правами админа) в шаблоне advanced фрэймворка YII2?, для того чтобы использовать backend (панель управления).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Просто зарегистрируй пользователя. Первый зарегистрированный пользователь будет обладать правами администратора.

Comment: Не совсем верный ответ, по умолчанию нет разделения на администраторов! Все пользователи в backend и frontend - пользователи без ролей (просто зарегать по умолчанию можно только из frontend)

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы было разделение прав на администратора и пользователей необходимо реализовать это самостоятельно - [RBAC в Yii2](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/security-authorization.md#%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-rbac)